# Python subprocess.run encoding failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, subprocess

I wanted to make a list of Turkish lemmas. So I downloaded codes from https://github.com/akoksal/Turkish-Lemmatizer and wrote a code to classify words by roots. The list of words is from https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/Turkish.
Here is the code I wrote:

```py
e='u8'
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir("C:/Users/(a directory)")
f=open('turkishforms.txt','r',encoding=e)
F=f.read()
print(len(F))
F=F.split('\n')
#print(F[:10])
d=dict()
i=0
f.close()
for r in F:
    r=r.rsplit('\t',1)
    r[-1]=int(r[-1])
    #print(r)
    o=subprocess.run('python3 lemmatizer.py '+r[0],capture_output=True,encoding=e,shell=True,check=True)
    #print(o)
    l=o.stdout.split('\n')
    l=l[1]
    #print(l)
    try:d[l]+=r[-1]
    except KeyError:d[l]=r[-1]
    i+=1
    print('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(i,r[0],r[-1],l,d[l]))
g=open('turkishlemmas.txt','w',encoding=e)
for r in d:
    t='{}\t{}\n'.format(r,d[r])
    print(t)
    g.write(t)
g.close()
```

and here is the initial part of the contents of the file named `turkishforms.txt` and encoded with UTF-8:

> ve 323574
> bir 269440
> bu  112290
> da  96026
> de  91520
> için 80977
> ile 76408
> Bu  65171
> olarak  59677
> çok  50031
> (continues)

(Note that the spaces in that quote above are all `\t`s.)
I tried `shell=True` and `check=True` as suggested, and I got this error:

> Exception in thread Thread-12:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
>     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1479, in _readerthread
>     buffer.append(fh.read())
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
>     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 69: invalid continuation byte
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\Users\(a directory)\lemmatiser.py", line 17, in 
>     o=subprocess.run('python3 lemmatizer.py  '+r[0],capture_output=True,encoding=e,shell=True,check=True)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
>     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python3 lemmatizer.py için' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I regard it weird that I got no error when running this at Colaboratory and debugging locally. Nonetheless, I want to run this locally because the former asks me not to be away from the keyboard, and the latter is so slow. Wouldn't there be any way to solve this problem?

Comment: **1st** Try `print(o.stderr)`. **2nd**  What if you run `python3 lemmatizer.py için` directly from an open `cmd` prompt?

Comment: Hello, @JosefZ. I appreciate your attention. I tried the first option and the same error still occurs, while the second option worked.